# Can't touch/connect to a unix socket from the same group

Tags: debian, permissions, socket, redis, debian-jessie

`sudo ls -la /var/lib/redis/6379/` produces:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 redis redis    4096 Nov 28 23:10 .
drwx-w---- 3 redis redis    4096 Nov 22 00:10 ..
srwxrwx--- 1 redis redis       0 Nov 28 23:10 redis.sock
```

Great, now `sudo groups www-data` produces:

`www-data : www-data redis`

OK, but then `sudo -u www-data -g www-data touch /var/lib/redis/6379/redis.sock` causes the following error:

`touch: cannot touch ‘/var/lib/redis/6379/redis.sock’: Permission denied`

This shouldn't happen to my understanding. Can someone point out where I'm completely wrong? The following doesn't work either with the same error (which is what I'm actually interested in):

`sudo -u www-data -g www-data redis-cli -s /var/lib/redis/6379/redis.sock` with

`Could not connect to Redis at /var/lib/redis/6379/redis.sock: Permission denied`

This is on Debian 8.2.

Comment: did you check SELinux permissions?

Comment: Did you tried `sudo -u www-data -g redis` ?

Comment: @Froggiz yup, I did, same result.

Comment: @Nik this is Debian, I think it's disabled by default - not sure how to check? `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the grandparent missing the `x`-bit. Now no permission issues!

Comment: What do you mean by the "grandparent"? I'm having this exact same issue with my socket in `/var/run/redis/redis.sock` - redis.sock has 770 permissions, and the parent dir (`/var/run/redis`) has 775 and both /var and /var/run have global execute permissions.

Comment: As I have observed, to use a UNIX socket, user needs rw permission for the socket itself and also posses execute (x) permission for all the parent folders of the socket.